# Silverlight Charting Toolkit: Are Interactive Charts possible?

Tags: silverlight, user-interface, charts, silverlight-toolkit

Has anyone tried or successfully implemented interactivity in the charts of the Silverlight Charting Toolkit? I want to grab a column for instance and move it up, so that the bound value is increased through my interaction with the chart.

I know there are commercial alternatives out there but really would like to know if it is possible with the toolkit or only achievable with disproportionate effort.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For example, here is my answer where I said how to add new value by click: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852772/allow-a-user-to-create-a-line-series-on-a-wpf-chart-by-clicking-on-the-chart/4855493#4855493 Also I conceive how to create drag-n-droppable datapoints for line series. Column series aren't so easy, so I'm not sure if it is possible to implement grabbing and moving up.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll try my luck on this.

Comment: I have used the Silverlight Toolkit charts for a reasonable amount of interactivity but haven't tried your (very cool) idea. I would imagine that the charts are only bound OneWay so direct manipulation is probably not possible. Therefore, if it were me, I would look to template the ChartPoint control and implement a Behavior<T> that wires to various events on the control such that mouse movements could modify values on the underlying DataContext. Perhaps use a Thumb primitive within the template to automate the dragging and attach the Behavior to that?

Just my initial thoughts. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but since the question has been sitting since March, I'll post it anyway.

Try Telerik's RadChart control. It supports a lot more than the standard stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has a wide variety of interactive charts including this [one](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/DragAndDrop) that you can play around with. You may want to start with this [page](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/FirstLook) and click the "Other Chart Examples" drop down to see what they have to offer.